# How to update excel sheet row from C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I'm frustrated because i can't solve this problem...

Well, i has been making a desktop application in C#, i almost complete the application,
But i have a big problem.

My application import an excel workbook who has some information that it is showed in a Gridview.
It works ok, but my app update or modified the data that is showed in a gridview, only one column that is called Balance.

I want to update this column in my excel workbook, is like an update condition in SQL, for example
I have this information that is imported to my app.

[image: Excel Workbook]

If i modify in my app some row, for example the row that has the order "12345", i want to update in my excel workbook the column called Balance of that row.

I has been trying with this code:

```
    string order = textBox1.Text;
    string balance = textBox2.Text;

    filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
    header = "Yes";
    OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(conStr); ;
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    string sql = null;
    MyConnection.Open();
    myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
    sql = "UPDATE [" + sheetName + "] SET [" + sheetName + "].[Order]=123 WHERE [" + sheetName + "].[Balance]=12313";
    myCommand.CommandText = sql;
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MyConnection.Close();
```

And if i debug the code it is the sentence that is executed, and i think that it is ok, but it doesn't works.

```
UPDATE ['12234$'] SET ['12234$'].[Order]=123 WHERE ['12234$'].[Balance]=12313
```

It give me this error:

```
Message=No value given for one or more required parameters.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a thought - but is your SQL-like string set up correctly?

If you're trying to update the balance for a certain order, you'd want that to be in your SET command.

So, something along the lines of...

```
UPDATE ['12234$'] SET ['12234$'].[Balance]=12313 WHERE ['12234$'].[Order]=12345
```

Comment: My SQLConnection is good, because is the same connection that i use to import the excel workbook, anyway is this:         private string Excel03ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";
        private string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";

Comment: Right, but you mentioned that in order to update the excel sheet you use a command similar to SQL.  I'm not questioning your connection. The SQL string provided at the bottom doesn't seem to be updating the balance like you want... instead, it would be updating the order number to '123' wherever a balance of '12313' is recorded in your sheet.

Comment: Thank you, i fix it, the problem is that the column that i try to update has a formula.

Comment: Gotcha - well, I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 4):

Consider using an NuGet package to work with Excels instead. [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is an excellent one.

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(@"someFile.xlsx")
{
   var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
   sheet.Cells["E2"].Value = 12345.32M;
   package.Save();
}
```

Sql is no longer possible, but you can use Linq:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(@"someFile.xlsx")
{
   var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
   int rowIndex = sheet.Cells["C2:C5"].First(x => int.Parse(x.Value.ToString()) == 12345).Start.Row;
   const int balanceColumnIndex = 5;
   sheet.Cells[rowIndex, balanceColumnIndex].Value = 12313M;
   package.Save();
}
```

I wrote [a series about EPPlus on my blog](http://pongit.be/tags/excel/).

Answer (score 0):

//try this solution

```
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/swtlist.xlsx;" +
                     @"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;';Persist Security Info=False;";


        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE  [Feuil1$]  SET d='yes' ", connection);

                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
```